# Django Empty Date Field With SQLITE

Tags: django, sqlite

In my models under the class I have this column in my rows that once a client accepts a quote it will be filled in so it can be empty.

```
quote_accepted = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to be able to pull all lines where the quote_accepted field is not set.

Some of the Ways I Tried:

```
"awaiting_quote": Order.objects.filter(quote_accepted='')
"awaiting_quote": Order.objects.filter(quote_accepted=' ')
"awaiting_quote": Order.objects.filter(quote_accepted='True')
"awaiting_quote": Order.objects.filter(quote_accepted='TRUE')
"awaiting_quote": Order.objects.filter(quote_accepted='Null')
"awaiting_quote": Order.objects.filter(quote_accepted='NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
Order.objects.filter(quote_accepted__isnull=True)
```